# Как из команды файла ***.form перевести в код java

Tags: java, swing

Возник вопрос, можно ли перевести то описание элементов, кнопок разделителей и т.д. на swing при создании формы в код java. т.е. когда я создаю файл с расширением ***.form у меня создается описание расположения элементов, а в связном классе всего лишь значения этих переменных. есть ли инструмент, который переводил описание элементов в код java на примере:

```
 <component id="7f2ef" class="javax.swing.JButton" binding="button1" default-binding="true">
        <properties>
          <font name="Harlow Solid Italic" size="12" style="0"/>
          <text value="Button"/>
        </properties>
      </component>

в 

 button1.setFont(new Font("Harlow Solid Italic", Font.PLAIN, 12));
```

Comment: Не понимаю смысла этого подхода. Люди потратили тысячи человеко-часов, чтобы сэкономить миллионы чеовеко-часов других разработчиков, которым больше не нужно каждый объект описывать сотнями строк кода, адостаточно лишь 3-10 строк на xml... Вообще вы вообще можете отказаться от xml и полностью описывать разметку в коде, но очень долго и выглядит, простите, мерзко. Читать это невозможно. Может я все же не понял зачем это?

Comment: ах да, я забыл упомянуть, я только только изучаю java. и только в этих целях

Comment: Тогда я могу только подтвердить, что да, это возможно, и опираясь на субъективное мнение посоветовать поучиться другими способами...) Если хотите поглубже покопаться в графическом интерфейса, то хотя бы возьмитесь за javaFX. Swing слишком устарел и активно вытесняются